# MongoDB: find between two dates doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to find between two dates. I have seen other similar questions on Stackoverflow.

My query should return 0 documents but i don't know why it is returning the document.

field:

```
"dates": [
    {
      "$date": "2023-04-08T14:37:02.937Z"
    },
    {
      "$date": "2023-04-15T14:37:02.937Z"
    },
    {
      "$date": "2023-04-23T14:37:02.937Z"
    }
  ],
```

My query :

```
{ dates: {$gte:ISODate('2023-04-18'), $lt: ISODate('2023-04-20') } }
```

This query should return 0 documents but instead it returns the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$elemMatch`:

```
db.collection.find({
  dates: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $gte: ISODate("2023-04-18"),
      $lt: ISODate("2023-04-20")
    }
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yqBUHYmfSZq)

Comment: It does work :), can i know why it isn't working without $elemMatch?

Comment: Without checking **each specific** item (`$elemMatch`), you do have an item which matches the first condition and **another** item that matches the second one, so the document is returned.